# What is RxJava equivalent of orElse

Tags: android, rx-java

There is one common operation in stream/functional land in other languages, that's orElse(). It serves like an if, where when the current chain didn't get any result, it changes to the alternate one. In a language with Maybe types it'd basically continue the chain for a Some type or change to the orElse on a None type.

Ideal case:

```
Observable.just(false)
          .filter(value -> { return value; })
          .map(value -> { return 1; })
          .orElse(Observable.just(0));

Observable.<Boolean>error(new IllegalStateException("Just playing"))
          .filter(value -> { return value; })
          .map(value -> { return 1; })
          .orElse(Observable.just(0));
```

It can be currently reproduced using concat and takeFirst, but it's just not semantically the same, and doesn't cover error handling properly.

```
Observable.concat(Observable.just(false)
                            .filter(value -> { return value; })
                            .map(value -> { return 1; }), 
                  Observable.just(0))
          .takeFirst();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like they have that, but with different naming: [defaultIfEmpty](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defaultifempty.html) or switchIfEmpty.

```
Observable.just(false)
        .filter(value -> value)
        .map(value -> 1)
        .defaultIfEmpty(0)
        .subscribe(val -> {
            // val == 0
        });

Observable.just(false)
        .filter(value -> value)
        .map(value -> 1)
        .switchIfEmpty(Observable.just(0))
        .subscribe(val -> {
            // val == 0
        });

// Error thrown from the first observable
Observable.<Boolean>error(new IllegalStateException("Crash!"))
        .filter(value -> value)
        .map(value -> 1)
        .switchIfEmpty(Observable.<Integer>error(new IllegalStateException("Boom!")))
        .subscribe(val -> {
            // never reached
        }, error -> {
            // error.getMessage() == "Crash!"
        });

// Error thrown from the second observable
Observable.just(false)
        .filter(value -> value)
        .map(value -> 1)
        .switchIfEmpty(Observable.<Integer>error(new IllegalStateException("Boom!")))
        .subscribe(val -> {
            // never reached
        }, error -> {
            // error.getMessage() == "Boom!"
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't handle error cases though, you'd need onErrorResumeNext or onErrorReturn.

Comment: Hi @MLProgrammer-CiM. I think it should handle error cases ok. I've added additional examples of how I'd catch it from the first or second observable. (btw, coding is magic I assume? cool;)

Comment: Those doesn't cover my case. Imagine that the starting observable fails, instead of being a just, but I still want to change the switchIfEmpty route, because that's what orElse would do.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, in that case you'd need one of those onError operators (or a custom built operator)