# How can I compare results from Observables and return one of them

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I have method to return object of Place, but first i have to check if Place object exist in database then return him or otherwise fetch Place object from rest service. How the easiest way I can check it out ?

```
public Observable<Place> getPlace(final String id) {

    // Both method from repository and rest are: Observable<Place> getPlace(String id);

    // if placeDatabaseRepository.getPlace(id) != null then:
    return placeDatabaseRepository.getPlace(id);
    // else Place == NULL then:
    return placeRest.getPlace(id);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is RxJava equivalent of orElse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833705/what-is-rxjava-equivalent-of-orelse)

Comment: You can use `switchIfEmpty` operator on your observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan Lew wrote [an excellent article](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/) about this very problem.

The gist of it is that you use two `Observable<Place>` instances - one that returns the result from the database if it's not null, another that returns the result from the REST call. You chain them together with the `concat()` operator and only take the first emitted item with the `first()` operator, kind of like so:

```
Observable<Place> dbSource = Observable
    .just(placeDatabaseRepository.getPlace(id))
    .filter(place -> place != null);
Observable<Place> restSource = Observable
    .just(placeRest.getPlace(id));

return Observable
    .concat(dbSource, restSource)
    .first();
```

Comment: That post suggest using a first(condition) on the concat observable. Your code snippet applies a filter to the database observable instead. What's the reason for that variation? I used the method in the blog post and it would not work when the database was empty (the rest observable did not run); your suggestion here would work though.

Comment: Hmm, that's very puzzling. I wrote the filter on the DB source as a matter of preference - I didn't even assume that it would make a difference... This requires some debugging.

Comment: If placeDatabaseRepository is null, you would get a NPE, which would not be passed down the chain. Maybe use something like Objects.requireNonNull(placeDatabaseRepository) and remove the null-filter. The null-filter would only be necessary if you would get "null" in the pipeline as a result. For the methods "getPlace" I would use a timeout. If one of the observables does not produce a value / does not complete you would block forever.

Comment: Good points, but the original question does not seem to define the `placeDatabaseRepository` as a possibly null value. I don't know if a normally functioning database can ever time out - maybe it's best to let it block forever so that the dev's attention is drawn to the underlying issue. But the REST call really should have a timeout associated with it. The problem is that we do not know if the underlying REST repository has a timeout mechanism itself and assuming that it does not is potentially dangerous.